# Scikit learn-find best C & gamma by GridSearchCV () __I'm stuck

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using GridSearchCV to get the best parameters (C & gamma) for my SVR model and when I run it I get stuck for hours and no results, so what is wrong with this code?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
C_range = np.logspace(-2, 10, 13)
gamma_range = np.logspace(-9, 3, 13)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf'), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
grid.fit(X, y)

print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.2f"
  % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
```

Answer (score 0):

`n_splits` is not a param of `sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit` instead it is a param for `sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit`.

From the [code base](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py) of `sklearn.cross_validation`:

```
class ShuffleSplit(BaseShuffleSplit):
    """Random permutation cross-validation iterator.

     .. deprecated:: 0.18
        This module will be removed in 0.20.
        Use :class:`sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit` instead.
```

Comment: I updated and the error is fixed but I have another error now... TypeError 'KFold' object is not iterable

Comment: `cv` param cannot take `KFold` as input. If you want `5` splits give `cv=5` as the input and it will use `KFold` or `StratifiedKFold` to generate the splits. See documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics).